# Python long running process

Tags: python

I have a Python web application in which one function that can take up to 30 seconds to complete.

I have been kicking off the process with a cURL request (inc. parameters) from PHP but I don't want the user staring at a blank screen the whole time the Python function is working.

Is there a way to have it process the data 'in the background', e.g. close the http socket and allow the user to do other things while it continues to process the data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an asynchronous data approach  to transfer data from a PHP script - or directly from the Python script, to an already rendered HTML page on the user side.

Check a javascript framework for the way that is easier for you to do that (for example, jquery). Then return an html page minus results to the user, with the javascript code to show a "calculating" animation, and fetch the reslts, in xml or json from the proper URL when they are done.